# Equation calculations with 4D arrays

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

Basically I have over 1000 3D arrays with the shape `(100,100,1000)`. So some pretty large arrays, which I need to use in some calculations. The great thing about python and Numpy is that instead of interations, calculations on each element and such can be done very quickly. For example, I can make a sum of each index for each 3D array almost instant. The result is one large array with the sum of each index for each array. In principle, that is ALMOST what I want to do, however, there is a bit of a problem.

What I need to do is use an equation that looks like this:

[image]

So as stated, I have around 1000 3D arrays. In total, the shape of this total array is `(1000, 100, 100, 1000)`. For each of the 1000 I also have a list going from 1 to 1000 that corresponds to the 1000 3D arrays, and each index of that list contains either a `1` or a `0`. If it has a `1` that entire 3D array of that index should go in the first term of the equation, and if `0`, it goes into the other.

I am however very much in doubt about how I am going to do this without turning to some kind of looping that might destroy the speed of the calculations by a great deal.

Comment: Try something, and if it is indeed too slow, come back and ask a specific question. SO is not a free coding site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could sort it by locating the 1's and 0's.
Something like:

```
list_ones = np.where(Array[0] == 1)
list_zeros = np.where(Array[0] == 0)
```

Then `Array[list_ones,:,:,:]` will contain all elements corresponding to a one and `Array[list_zeros,:,:,:]` will correspond to all elements corresponding to a zero.

Then you can just put

```
first_term = Array[list_ones,:,:,:]
second_term = Array[list_zeros,:,:,:]
```

And sum as appropriate.

Would this work for your purpose?